# What is a principal formula??

Tags: logic

I am studying structural proof theory by Sara Negri, but I am having a problem, I can't understand what  a principal formula is ? When she wants to prove a lemma or a theorem, she  divides it into two conditions $(1)$When the formula is principal and $(2)$when its not. Whats the reason behind it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See page 15 :

> The formula with the connective in a rule is the *principal* formula of that rule,
>   and its components in the premisses are the *active formulas*. The Greek letters
>   denote possible additional assumptions that are not active in a rule; they are called
>   the *contexts* of the rules.

The principal fromula is the one "acted on" by the rule : reading the rule bottom-up, the principal formula is "decomposed" by the rule according to the corresponding connective, while the formulae in the context are left unchanged.

Comment: tnx.your answer was helpful.can you explain more about this sentence in page 32 please: "if A&B is not principal in the last rule,it has one OR two (???) premisses A&B,Γ′⇒C′ ,A&B,Γ′′⇒c″.....tnx alot

Comment: @fatima - the proof is by *induction* on the number $n$ of rules applied and the phrase is relative to the *induction step*. It is splitted into two case : *i)* A&B principal; *ii)* A&B **not** principal: this means that the said occurrence of A&B is in one of the contexts of the rule applied (which is not L&) and some rule (see page 28) has only one premise while some rule has two premsies. Because it is **not** principal (it occurs in a context) it is left unchanged by the applied rule in the original proof; thus, apply the induction hypo to them.

Comment: tnx alot for your helpful answer.